# C# I give value but cant get it back in other parts

Tags: c#, variables

im new here and also new to C# so go easy on me :)

Im trying to write a piece of code that will take a given number and create sets of 4 while staying under the number. Example i use in my code is, sets of 4.

Meaning: If i have 10 blocks and want to make sets of 4 it will divide 10 by 4 (2,5) round that off (down) to 2. And then * 4 to get amount of sets i can get.

so this is what i came up with:

```
    public double buysession;

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double Value1 = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        double divideby = 4;
        double Calcstuff = Value1 / divideby;
        double Rounded1 = Math.Floor(Calcstuff);
        double buysession = Rounded1 * 4;
        {

            label1.Text = "you can get " + Rounded1.ToString() +" sets";
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(buysession.ToString());
    }
```

But the problem is when i call the messagebox via button 2 it shows that buysession has value 0 instead of 8 (if i put the Messagebox.Show in button1 it does return 8 as a value for buysession).

How do i make it so that the value i give to buysession at button1 becomes a global thing i can use and call in the rest of the program???

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what's going on? Be aware, `Math.Floor(0.5)` returns `0`. BTW, why `buysession` is a field, not a local variable?

Comment: Yes, Its supposed to return 0 if the var Calcstuff is 0.5, I'm relatively new to all this and started working with little knowledge i had from a book that i read a long while back. The reason i put Public infront is cause i thought it was not being seen cause it was private or whatnot (read public private somewhere as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating the local variable named "buysession" and setting value to it. That is why your "buysession" field is still null.

Exchange the line

```
double buysession = Rounded1 * 4;
```

with

```
buysession = Rounded1 * 4;
```

Comment: Yes like with the awnser below, i was making a "new" variable that got the value locally within button1, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `button2` handler, you are displaying the value of the `buysession` member variable (which always has a value of 0).  In your `button1` handler, you are declaring a local variable named `buysession` (which has your calculated value of 8).

I have changed the code below to always use the class member `buysession`:

```
 public double buysession;

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double Value1 = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        double divideby = 4;
        double Calcstuff = Value1 / divideby;
        double Rounded1 = Math.Floor(Calcstuff);
        this.buysession = Rounded1 * 4;    // CHANGE HERE
        label1.Text = "you can get " + Rounded1.ToString() +" sets";

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.buysession.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: ahh, so by putting double infront in the button's code, i make it a local variable within the "button1". Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
public double buysession;
double Value1;
double divideby;
double Calcstuff;
double Rounded1;
double buysession;
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Value1 = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    divideby = 4;
    Calcstuff = Value1 / divideby;
    Rounded1 = Math.Floor(Calcstuff);
    double buysession = Rounded1 * 4;
    {

        label1.Text = "you can get " + Rounded1.ToString() +" sets";
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(buysession.ToString());
}
```

off the top of my head this should work

Comment: This creates 2 problems (1 being double buysession creating an Ambiguity, removing one of the buysessions solves this problem, but not the next) and it still spits out 0 as the value for buysession via button 2.

Comment: oh sorry i missed that last double... my bad... not running this through and IDE